# how to solve this mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 3 mysql tables

- `user(u_id(p),name)`,
- `team(t_id(p),u_id(f),t_name,t_money,days_money)` and
- `history(t_id(f),day,d_money)`.

Now I have to display leaderboard using php.

I tried this.

```
SELECT t_id FROM team;
```

got result.

then,
in for loop

```
foreach($tid_all as $tid)
{
     $que = $db_con->prepare("SELECT d_money, t_name FROM team, history WHERE t_id= '".$tid['t_id']."' && day='1'");

     $que->execute();

        while($info = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
        {

                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo  "<td>".$info[0]."</td>";
                  echo  "<td>".$info[1]."</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
         }
}
```

but it didnt work. any solution?

Solution 1:
 i tried this and it worked.

```
`SELECT d_money, t_name FROM team, history WHERE history.t_id=$tid['t_id'] AND team.t_id=history.t_id`
```

is it correct way or not?

thanks everyone for help.

Question : is it possible to order the result table by d_money? i want it in descending order.

Comment: Please define "didn't work." What did you expect to happen and what really happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `&&` with `AND`.Try like this :

```
"SELECT d_money, t_name FROM team, history WHERE t_id= '".$tid['t_id']."' AND day='1' order by d_money DESC "
```

Comment: i tried this and it worked. SELECT d_money, t_name FROM team, history WHERE history.t_id=$tid['t_id'] && team.t_id=$tid['t_id']  ..is it correct way or not?

Comment: now your code is ok.Try to use join when ever you load data from more then one table.

Comment: check my answer with edits.You only have to add `order by money desc` to your query.

Comment: It didnt work. I think it displays single row in table as i'm using foreach loop. is there any other way?

Comment: first load all ids in array.then use `where in` condition on query.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `&&` in MySQL Query. Replace that with **`AND`** Operator on your query.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to get the data from the two tables, then [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the two tables instead of doing that with a loop:

```
SELECT
  h.d_money,
  t.t_name
FROM team AS t
INNER JOIN history AS h ON t.t_id = h.t_id;
```

Run this single query once and you will get what you want. You can also add a `WHERE` clause at the end of it the way you did in your query.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT d_money, t_name FROM team, history WHERE team.t_id= '".$tid['t_id']."' AND history.t_id= '".$tid['t_id']."' && day='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace

```
 WHERE t_id= '".$tid."' AND day='1'
```

instead of

```
 WHERE t_id= '".$tid['t_id']."' && day='1'
```